# mysql: How do you determine the ideal 'open_files_limit' setting value?

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

I am facing this issue:
https://serverfault.com/questions/104618/out-of-resources-for-mysqldump

Questions

- I know I need to increase open_files_limit, but to how much?
- Can I call a command in mysql that tells me how much this should be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may find this surprising, but mysqld actually determines the correct value for you upon startup.

[**The MySQL Documentation says the default value for `open_files_limit` is 0**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_open-files-limit). Yet, when you run the command `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'open_files_limit';`, it does not come back with 0. It returns what mysqld would comfortably run with.

The MySQL Documentation says the maximum value for `open_files_limit` is 65535. I have seen some systems with the setting above 100000 upon startup (132332 to be exact). That being the case, there are some instances where you cannot set `open_files_limit` any higher.

Just run the command I mentioned

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'open_files_limit';
```

If the number comes back less that 65535, you can experiment with higher values up to 65535.

Keep in mind two more things

- If you are using InnoDB with [**innodb_file_per_table**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) enabled, you have to set [**innodb_open_files** (Default is set to 300)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_open_files).
- Keep your eye on the error log. It will post a warning if your setting for `open_files_limit` is too high.